# Do Repository, Data Mapper and Data Access Object work independently or collaboratively?

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern, data-access-layer, dao, datamapper

In my opinion,

- A **repository** acts like a collection object which returns or operates a list of domain objects according to a criteria input.
- A **data mapper** acts as a middle layer between database and the domain layer to hide the persistence implementation (such as SQL statements).
- A **data access object** is a common interface of the whole persistence layer.

I think since the implementation of a **data access object** has a **repository**, and the implementation of the **repository** has a **data mapper** and sometimes **a identity map** to make the domain object unique, Is it correct to say that they work collaboratively? Or they are completely difference patterns that do not work with each other?

Answer (score 1):

Most time the repository is belong to Domain layer which is all domain object(Entity) reconstructor.

And data mapper is worked with DAO and they are all belong to infrastructure layer, DAO is the low level persistence interface which only return some DTO(data transmission object)

DAO should used by repository to reconstructor our domain entity with more than one DTO.

**If you question is "Is it correct to say that they work collaboratively", the answer is partly correct because the Data Mapper is a kind of DAO**

Sorry for my bad english.